# Reduced efficiency of open MP over time

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have a large calculation algorithm where I use open mp to help speed it up. It works fine for the first 50 or so iterations (i.e. until y = 50 or so), but then starts to slow down progressively. I also notice that the CPU usage goes from ~100% to ~40% by the end.

The code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <ipp.h>



void main(){
    std::string filename = "Large_File.file";
    FILE * fid = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");    
    Ipp32f* vector= ippsMalloc_32f(100000000);

    for (int y=0; y<300; y++){

        fread(vector,sizeof(float),100000000,fid);

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int x=0; x<300; x++){

            //A time-consuming calculation

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This question lacks basic information. What OS? What hardware? How much RAM? I would hypothesise that it is something related to OS I/O buffering as you are reading 224 GiB of data in total. After 50 iterations you've read 37 GiB and if the system has 32 GiB of RAM, parts of working set including `vector` might get paged to the disk which will slow down further access. It could also be a NUMA-related issue. Use an instrument like `vmstat` (if running on a Unix-like OS) or Intel VTune to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

OS is windows 7, 48GB RAM, 6 cores, 12 logical processors.

I don't believe it's a RAM issue, since the memory usage stays constant at around 12 or so GB. I'll look into the NUMA possibility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, check if this exactly the same question and *the same answer* as given stackoverflow link: [Why does moving the buffer pointer slow down fread (C programming language)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038509/why-does-moving-the-buffer-pointer-slow-down-fread-c-programming-language)
   (It's not very far from what Hristo suggested)
2. Secondly, from the way you stated your question and "common sense" it is most likely that the slowdown is driven by "fread" call (as an only thing to vary with "y" increase from what could be seen in your "restricted" example).
3. Third side comment: since you use IPP, you are likely to use fresh (likely Intel) Compiler. If so, I would suggest using more novel ways of allocating memory in aligned manner: either _aligned_malloc() or using `#include <aligned_new>` [read more](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/aligned-operator-new-support-in-intel-c-compiler)

(I assume you expect to hear more about OpenMP-specific slow-downs but it's pretty low probability that there is any relationship wrt threading in your case; you may possibly verify it by disabling OpenMP and comparing y=50, y=100, y=150, .. runs, although it will not prove a lot in case you really deal with sophisticated NUMA/threading composability issues which again I don't beleive is the case)

Comment: I don't believe it's the fread that is slowing down. Even on the last iteration, the fread part of the code only takes a few seconds. It's the calculation that goes from about 30 seconds to several minutes. That, combined with the reduced cpu usage seems to argue for something to do with my multithreading.

Comment: You said that fread takes few seconds. Does it mean you was able to profile your code? If so, what were formal hotspots in the profile?  Again, theoretically many things are possible, but practically you incrementally read huge amount of data and at the same time observe behavior pretty common for swapping/disc-cache/inefficient IO use cases. Did you  have a chance to look at the link with answer provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038509/why-does-moving-the-buffer-pointer-slow-down-fread-c-programming-language  (should be quick exercise to verify if it helps in your case)